# How to send push notification to client app from merchant app?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notification to the client app from the merchant app. Both are two different android apps. How can I achieve this using `FCM` or any other service?
Do I need to have both these apps in the same `Firebase` project or different firebase projects?

Comment: Same project for both apps, keep merchant and client in separate collections. Also use Cloud Functions to actually send the notification instead of sending it directly from app.

Comment: Thanks @ZohaibAmir ! I am doing the same but in the cloud functions how do i access both collections?

Comment: I think you are confusing trigger event functions with normal ones, in normal functions you can use Firestore library just like you do in Android or Web. In the documentation for Firestore, switch to Web/NodeJS code. You can simply make two instances each pointing to a collection: `var merchant = db.collection("merchant); var client = db.collection("clients");

Answer (score 1):

In order to send messages, use FCM Rest API

POST_API_URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/

Header :

1) Authorization : key=legacy_server_key

2) Content-Type : application/json

Body:

{
"to":"receiver push token",
"notification":{
"title":"",
"body":""
},
"data":{
},
"android":{
"priority":"high"
},
"apns":{
"headers":{
"apns-priority":"10"
},
"payload":{
"headers":{
"category":"abc"
}
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do that either with one firebase project or two .. it dosen't really matter.. You should use a webservice (API) as a proxy to send notification.

In order to send messages you can use a set of languages or use a the rest API (hitting *https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send*) provided by the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message)